# suggested edits purely consisting of fixing capitalization (i -> I)?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, capitalization

So I came across the first one which changed a few "i" into "I" and rejected it for being too minor, then came across another one - looks like there's a user that's been [doing this for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339122/lain?tab=activity&sort=revisions) based on their revision history... **and they're getting accepted.**

Should these be getting accepted? Basically all of these seem "too minor" to me...

Comment: They are "too minor" for me, I have given up on edit reviews, as by the time I think about an edit someone else has aproved it.

Comment: I approve those, I agree they're kind of minor but it's really annoying to see people use lowercase "i" , might be a form of OCD on my part.

Comment: Both these comments are true  - it depends on what else is wrong in the edit (and in at lease one of the edits the first word change is misspelt)

Comment: How is that too minor? Isn't that a typical error that needs to be corrected? It's not like you can choose to use lowercase "I"…

Comment: It's also much quicker to approve than to reject. So unless something is *actively* wrong with the edit, it's understandable people prefer approving.

Comment: Unless there's nothing they could have _obviously_ improved, I tend to reject these types of suggested edits.

Comment: I have OCD and I am one of those people who goes and fixes the i's to I's :P (as well as the other mistakes in it since I'm there already). There is a reason the min edit is 6 char, not like 40+. It is designed to allow changes such as this. You argument is it is to minor, so instead of fixing an ACTUAL error, you reject it and keep the post in worse condition than it was before? Seems silly to me:P

Comment: I assume the reason for minimum changes on edits is to avoid having lots of trivial changes in the review queue. Editing just for minor spelling, grammatical, and capitalization changes clogs up the review queue. That's why we have a "too minor" rejection reason -- we want to discourage these types of edits.

Comment: @Lain - there's a reason for the "too minor" rejection - posts can only be edited so many times before they become CW, which affects rep. Rather than fixing one small issue out of many, then having to come back over and over to fix the other small issues, we want to encourage edits to fix a majority of the issues with a post. I'm sure that many of those posts with a lowercase i have plenty of other problems that can be fixed at the same time.

Comment: @Chris I was referring to the questions that only have that left to fix. As in once that is fixed there really isn't anything left to fix on it. So if all that's left to edit is that then I see no problem with it. (Btw, the lower case I in your comment just kills me:D )